# Cardinality of a set of closed intervals

Tags: elementary-set-theory, cardinals

What is the cardinality of the set S of all closed intervals on the real number line with rational (positive) lengths?

I believe the number of intervals with a specific fixed length but varying start points is |**R**|, and the number of intervals with a fixed start point but varying lengths is |**Q**| = |**N**|. I think the answer to the question would then be |S| = |**R** x **N**| = |**R**|? I'm not quite sure how to prove the last equality though. Would I have to define a bijective function that maps elements of (**R**, **N**) to **R**? How would I approach doing so?

Comment: There are many mappings from $\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{N}$ to reals. For instance, $f(x,n)=\arctan x+\pi n$ is one of them (if you don't count the infinity into the $\mathbb{R}$, then you have $\mathbb{N}$ holes in the codomain, but that's not a problem, because $|\mathbb{N}|<|\mathbb{R}|$).

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

You can get a bijection from $\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{N}$ to $[0,\infty)$ by bijectively mapping (for each $n\in\mathbb{N}$), $\mathbb{R}\times\{n\}$ to $[n,n+1)$.